# What does "... have done with ..." mean here?

Tags: meaning

As for us, we have really had enough of repeating every day, that neither true freedom nor true emancipation of the world of labor, nor 'he true society, nor the new culture -- in short, that no real Socialist value can be achieved by means of a centralized "State apparatus" actuated by political power in the hands of a party. **Is it not time to have done with this subject**, in the hope that, tomorrow, life itself will make this truth (basically so simple) known with perfect clarity, to all the blind?
link: http://www.ditext.com/voline/271.html

Answer (score 1):

The phrase generally means to finish or settle argument or a difficult situation.  In the context of the text it implies the writer is saying (as a rhetorical question) that it is time put an end to the notion that Socialist value cannot be achieved by means of a centralized "State apparatus" actuated by political power in the hands of a party............... etc.